# Loading images in tableview asynch

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I run this code as an extension to imageView to load image to cells.the problem is images are loading to cells but all cells image are invisible or hidden till I click on one of them after that all cells images are shown !

```
extension UIImageView {
func downloadImageFrom(link:String, contentMode: UIViewContentMode) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask( with: NSURL(string:link)! as URL,    completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.contentMode =  contentMode
            if let data = data { self.image = UIImage(data: data) }
        }
    }).resume()
}
}
```

and in the cellforRowAt :

```
    cell.imageView?.downloadImageFrom (link)
```

Comment: You can use Alamofire image instead which is much easier.

Comment: You can use KingFisher library which is much faster and efficient also less number of code

Answer (score 0):

There is less info posted on question still I can assume following may be issue

-> Your cell has UIImageView and you are downloading image but after image download how you are notifying cell  ? ,

-> Since tableview reuse cells and your imageview will also been re used by tableview cell in your code you are just downloading image data and set to UIImageView  that will create problem in future

TIP:

1) Use disk or memory caching ,

2) Use placeholder image while your cell is downloading image

3) Use Completion handler (closure) to notify your cell when you have finished downloading

4) You can use third party library which is very ease to use like AlamofireImage or SDWebImage

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code : -

```
 extension UIImageView {

 static let cacheData = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()
 func downloadedFrom(link: String, placeHolder:String = "placeholder",isFromCache:Bool = true,isIndicator:Bool = true,isAppendBaseUrl:Bool = true) {

    let placeHolderImage = UIImage.init(named: placeHolder);
    self.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    self.clipsToBounds = true;
    self.image=placeHolderImage;
    var strlink = ""

    if isAppendBaseUrl
    {
        strlink =  "Your base url" +  link
    }
    else
    {
        strlink = link
    }
    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge)
            guard let url = URL(string: strlink) else
            {
                return
            }
            if isIndicator
            {
                activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width/2, y: self.bounds.size.height/2)
                activityIndicator.color = UIColor.white
                self.addSubview(activityIndicator)
                activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            }
            if isFromCache
            {
                if let cachedImage = UIImageView.cacheData.object(forKey: url as AnyObject) as? UIImage
                {

                    if isIndicator
                    {
                        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    }
                    self.image = cachedImage
                }
                else
                {
                    self.image = placeHolderImage
                    let urlStr = strlink
                    let url = URL(string: urlStr)

                    let request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)


                    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                    if error != nil
                    {
                        print(error!)

                        return
                    }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                            if isIndicator
                            {
                                activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                                activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview();
                            }
                            if (image != nil)
                            {
                            self.image = image

                            UIImageView.cacheData.setObject(image!, forKey: url as AnyObject)
                            }

                        })


                }).resume()
                }
            }
            else
            {
            self.image=placeHolderImage;
                let urlStr = strlink
                let url = URL(string: urlStr)

                var request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)

                request.setValue("xyz", forHTTPHeaderField:"DeviceId")

                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                    if error != nil
                    {
                        print(error!)

                        return
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        if isIndicator
                        {
                            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                            activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview();
                        }
                        if (image != nil)
                        {
                            self.image = image

                            UIImageView.cacheData.setObject(image!, forKey: url as AnyObject)
                        }

                    })
                }).resume()}
}}
```

Comment: why it does not work for you i am using it and i can load all the images just like you. if possible can you send me your url from which you are taking a link to download the images ?

Comment: I solved my problem by adding a subview in table cells and hold images in it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding a subview in table cells and hold images

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me. May be forgot to specify a method super.viewDidLoad() or super.viewDidAppear(true)...

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "idFriendCell", for: indexPath) as! FriendCell
    cell.fotoFriend.downloadImageFrom(link: "http://foto.jpg")
    return cell
}
extension UIImageView {
    func downloadImageFrom(link: String) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: link)!) { (data, response, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let data = data else { return }
                self.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```